# jQuery if condition for two element mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hereis the code and [online JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaUNY/):

```
<div class="blocka"></div>
<div class="blockb"></div>
```

```js
$(".blocka").mouseenter(function(){
     $(".blockb").show();
});
$(".blocka").mouseleave(function(){
     $(".blockb").hide();
});
```

My question is is it possible to have something like
`if $(".blocka") or $(".blockb")` mouseleave then hide `$(".blockb")`

I tried the following but it doesn't work :

```
$(".blocka" || ".blockb" ).mouseleave(function(){
     $(".blockb").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do multiple selections using a comma `,`:

```
$(".blocka, .blockb").mouseenter(function(){
     $(".blockb").show();
});
$(".blocka, .blockb").mouseleave(function(){
     $(".blockb").hide();
});
```

**Updated fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/jaUNY/3/

Comment: thanks I tried `$(".blocka, .blockb").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".blockb").hide();
});` it didnt work, I missed `$(".blocka, .blockb").mouseenter(function(){
});` thank you

Comment: yeah sorry, i had that in my answer before but because you only specified `leave` i removed it, then i figured you'd needed it so I put it back in :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".blocka, .blockb" ).mouseleave(function(){
         $(".blockb").hide();
    });
```

multiple selectors will work.
http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to keep blockb open when moving mouse from blocka to blockb, so the code would be:

```
$(".blocka, .blockb").hover(
    function() { $(".blockb").show() },
    function() { $(".blockb").hide() }
);
```